# How to upgrade python version inside a virtual environment (in windows)?

Tags: python, django, cmd

How to make my virtual environment use same version of python installed in my system. (see picture)
[image]

Comment: Create a new virtual environment that uses the latest python version. You can't update inside a virtualenv because every single package needs to be reinstalled if you update python.

Answer (score 0):

Using Conda you can update Python from within the environment that you are using.

```
conda activate test
conda update python
```

This will update python to the latest stable release.

Comment: trying it but i think its gonna take forever